# Loading a requests text response into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Trying to load text from a requests response into a Pandas dataframe.

```
url = "https://api.semrush.com/"

parameters = {"type": "phrase_organic",
                "key": "*****",
                "phrase": phrase,
                "database": "us",
                "display_limit": 2,
                "export_columns": "Dn,Ur"}

response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
urldata = response.text

dF = pd.read_csv(urldata)
```

The response text looks like this...

```
Domain;Url
facebook.com;https://facebook.com/home
instagram.com;https://instagram.com/home
```

The text is separated by semicolons. Domain and Url (first line) should be the name of the pandas columns. Everything else will be rows in the dataframe.

Comment: Could you be more explicit to what doesn't work? Could you use the `delimiter` argument in `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Domain;Url\r\nfacebook.com;https://facebook.com/home\r\ninstagram.com;https://instagram.com/home' does not exist:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pd.read_csv` takes a file or a buffer as input, not a plain string directly.

You can either save your data on disk first and then load it with pandas, or use `StringIO`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

pd.read_csv(StringIO(urldata), sep=';')
```